# ¿Cómo insertar un dato traído de Ajax en un atributo data de un HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Por cuestión de GUI se ha manejado este código html por dicha razón,

```
<div class="value white">
    <h1 class="timer" data-from="0" data-to=""
     data-speed="1000">
     <!--320-->
     </h1>
     <p>New Order</p>
</div>
```

En este momento por ajax automáticamente estoy trayendo desde el controlador un dato traído de la base de datos que es un simple numero `(COUNT(sql))`..

```
$.getJSON( "cant_orders", function( data ) 
{
    var resultado = data;
    console.info(resultado[0].cant);
});
```

como podría meter ese dato obtenido en el atributo `data-to=""` que se encuentra en el html?, ya que es de ahí donde se muestra el dato al usuario.

Agradecería el interés

Answer (score 3):

Bastante simple, con el método `attr` de jquery puedes lograr lo que deseas, más o menos así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '#add', function(e) {
    console.log($('.timer').attr('data-to'));
    $('.timer').attr('data-to', 'full'); // Esto es un ejemplo
    // $('.timer').attr('data-to', resultado[0].cant); Aquí lo harías dentro de tu getJSON
    console.log($('.timer').attr('data-to'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="value white">
  <h1 class="timer" data-from="0" data-to="empty" data-speed="1000">
    <!--320-->
  </h1>
  <p>New Order</p>
  <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

Es decir que tu código quedaría así:

```
$.getJSON( "cant_orders", function( data ) 
{
    var resultado = data;
    $('.timer').attr('data-to', resultado[0].cant);
});
```

Comment: Hola @Jorius he intentado hacer el codigo de quienes han respondido mi pregunta incluyendo el tuyo pero no me funciona e incluso no me muestra nada en la consola (hablo de un posible error), si imprimo resultado[0].cant me imprime el valor pero si trato de ingresarlo de esta manera $('.timer').attr('data-to', resultado[0].cant); no sucede nada

Comment: @Daniel ¿intentaste dandole un valor inicial al atributo data-to cómo en mi ejemplo? no lo dejes `data-to=""` intenta dandole un simple valor `data-to="algun_valor"`

Comment: Si, lo intente y no me ha funcionado

Comment: @Daniel ¿lo tienes dentro de un `document.ready`? quizás el getJSON se ejecuta antes de que el navegador procese correctamente el `DOM` es algo que suele pasar mucho